# Selenium - Using Java to download a set of links that use bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, glyphicons

I am currently having an issue trying to download a link on a page. It uses the bootstrap glyphicon "glyphicon-download". I cannot seem to find the correct Element. As can be seen on the far left side of the screenshot is the glyphicon, each one in the column is a separate download link.

So in short, i am having trouble finding the element (that I guess can be found from the html source code) so I can download a file.

All help appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the html code when I inspect the download element.

[image: Glyphicon HTML Code]

Here is my java code thus far

*SoltraHomePage.java (The part that matters related to this issue)*

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;


public class SoltraHomePage {

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "username") private WebElement Username;
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "password") private WebElement Password;
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "loginbutton") private WebElement loginbutton;
@FindBy(how = How.LINK_TEXT, using = "Feeds") private WebElement Feeds;
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "feedlist") private WebElement feedlist;
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "container") private WebElement container;
@FindBy(how = How.LINK_TEXT, using = "Default") private WebElement Default;
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "control-bar") private String control;
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "li.pull-right select") private WebElement soltraSelect;

public void Download(){
    **//Code here to download indicator//**
}
}
```

*SoltraDownload.java - The part that matters relating to this issue*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class SoltraDownload {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    //DOWNLOAD THE INDICATORS
    SoltraHomePage.Download();
    }

}
```

Comment: I remember a discussion about the unability of Selenium to download files because the Download dialog is created by the OS and thus cannot be interacted with. But since you didn't describe your issue, I cannot tell if it relates to what I say.

Comment: Most people on here do not have the rest of day to debug your code. How about narrowing it down a bit? Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: SiKing & Dmitry, I updated the question. I hope it's a bit more readable. Thanks for the pointers.